# Turret following the player in the opposite side

Tags: c#, rotation, godot

i have tried using lookout method then flipping it by 180 degress but it gives me the same result as the problem i had before.
my turret turns left when i move right and vica verse.
To fix this i used my trigonometry skills to get how much it need to turn on the x and y axis.but i still get the same trouble so i the result negetive but this in turn flips my character.
here is the code,i have modified it a bit so it wont look as nice as i am tired:(

```
 Vector3 distance = Trunk.GlobalPosition - TrackedObject.GlobalPosition;
 float rotatx = Mathf.Atan2(distance.Y , distance.Z);
 float rotatey=Mathf.Atan2(distance.X, distance.Z); //doing the opposite pattern
 Vector3 rot=Trunk.Rotation;
 Vector3 newrot =Trunk.Rotation;
 newrot.Y = rotatey;
 newrot.X = rotatx;
Trunk.Rotation = rot.Lerp(newrot, 0.1f);
```

here is a video to show the problem:
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Et_lR-kgwBo&ab_channel=KURENANI)
(dont mind the clear trigonometry problem,i was tired and mixed up pi/2 with 90)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i came up with:

```
Vector3 TargetDirection = Trunk.GlobalPosition - TrackedObject.GlobalPosition;
TargetDirection = TargetDirection.Normalized();
Basis temptrunk = Trunk.GlobalBasis;
temptrunk.Z = TargetDirection;
temptrunk.Y = TargetDirection.Cross(temptrunk.X);
temptrunk.X=TargetDirection.Cross(temptrunk.Y);
Trunk.GlobalBasis = temptrunk;
```

The reason why it works is becouse the vector from the trunk to the target is the direction the trunk should be pointing.
I then normalize it so that i only get the direction.
Then i set the z basis[think of the z basis as the face of the object,y basis as the angle in space of the object and the x axis as the side of the object] so it has the same direction.
Then i cross my y & x axis as i want my trunk to be scaled properly.
This can also be applied on the different basis,it is important to know what you want to face what.

Comment: This answer would be even more helpful to future readers with a little explanation clarifying why or how this code solves the problem.